# Как выделить максимальное количество памяти на C++?

Tags: c++, windows, память, malloc

Как выделить максимальное количество памяти на C++ под Windows, в идеале всю оперативную память?
Нужно запрашивать больше блок или лучше наоборот маленькие? Если запросить слишком много маленьких блоков не упрется ли это в ограничения ОС (или работа замедлится) до того как будет занята вся память?

Comment: Но зачем? Вы всё-равно не сможете гарантировать, что вся эта память останется в оперативке, возможно она начнёт частично уезжать в своп, если система подумает, что память сейчас нужнее другим приложениям. Либо в своп начнут уезжать другие приложения и да - работа системы тогда замедлится из-за этого.

Comment: Одним блоком захватить всю память невозможно. А вот несколькими кусками - чуть реальнее. Но даже в этом случае есть память, где размещается само приложение, операционная система и тому подобное. Но есть выход! пишите свою ОС - тогда вся память Ваша.  P.S. - вся память и все оперативная память и вся доступная память - это разные вещи.

Comment: Неужели нет способа это обойти? Я пишу программу сортировки файлов, не помещающихся в память. Сортирую по куску, который можно загрузить в память быстрой сортировкой. Затем сливаю эти куски сортировкой слиянием. Чтобы это работало максимально эффективно нужно знать сколько есть оперативной памяти и использовать только её (до слияния). Но свопинг все портит.

Answer (score -1):

Одним блоком захватить всю память невозможно. А вот несколькими кусками - чуть реальнее. Но даже в этом случае есть память, где размещается само приложение, операционная система и тому подобное. Вы всё-равно не сможете гарантировать, что вся эта память останется в оперативке, возможно она начнёт частично уезжать в своп, если система подумает, что память сейчас нужнее другим приложениям. Либо в своп начнут уезжать другие приложения и да - работа системы тогда замедлится из-за этого.